# How to pass arguments to a javascript function that is contained in a variable/object and has yet to be evaluated?

Tags: javascript

Currently I have functions like this.

```
var HelloByName = function greetingsByName( name ){console.log( 'hello' + name )}
```

I am trying to write a generic functionality for that would find the function on the page and pass parameters to it as needed. How can pass a parameters to a function that is in the variable form like?

Is there is anything like this:

```
todisplay =  window[HelloByName].passInParams( "name" , "Mike" );
```

which would change the value of HelloByName(name) into HelloByName("Mike")?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pass parameters into functions with a `param = value` syntax. And you can use `bind()` to create a partial function bound to specific arguments. Combined that would give you something like:

```js
var HelloByName = function greetingsByName( name ){console.log( 'hello ' + name )}

let param = "name"
let todisplay = window['HelloByName'].bind(null, [param] = "mark" );

todisplay()
```

Is that what you are after? Or are you just looking to bind parameters and make partials?

```js
var HelloByName = function greetingsByName( name ){console.log( 'hello ' + name )}

let HelloMike = HelloByName.bind(null, "Mike")
HelloMike()
```

Comment: Yep. It was the first. Can you explain what the null is for and maybe how you would add more params in there if the function accepts more than one?